# Generate UPC-A Barcode Image with reference barcodeString

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, zxing, barcode-printing

We are using Zxing API for generating string to upc-a barcode image. But that image contains only barcode, but not with string like as the image in below link:
https://postimg.org/image/7t66lqa83/

So please suggest us how to generate barcode image with both barcode and string Sean Owen

Answer (score 1):

UPC-A barcodes are designed for scanning products at a shop's checkout. They encode a world-wide unique 12 digit number for the product (13 digits for EAN-13 or GTIN-13, which is compatible with UPC-A). Product numbers are assigned by the international organization [GS1](http://www.gs1.org/).

Therefore, UPC-A barcode should not be used for anything else than to encode GS1 product numbers. And they are technically unable to encode strings.